# Convert gradient css comand to -moz-linear-gradient and -webkit-linear-gradient

Tags: css, gradient

I have the following css code which works just fine but when I try to convert it into moz-linear-gradient and -webkit-linear-gradient I get an error and it does not work:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0A1326 0%, #0A1326 35%, #ffffff00 35%, #ffffff00 100%);
```

Here is my try:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #0A1326 0%, #0A1326 35%, 
#ffffff00 35%, #ffffff00 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #0A1326 0%, #0A1326 35%, #ffffff00 35%, #ffffff00 100%);
```

How must this be writen exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, but not in chrome, `webkit` works in `safari` and `-moz-` works for `firefox`.
you just need to add all 3 like this:

```
h1 {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0A1326 0%, #0A1326 35%, #ffffff00 35%, #ffffff00 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #0A1326 0%, #0A1326 35%, #ffffff00 35%, #ffffff00 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #0A1326 0%, #0A1326 35%, #ffffff00 35%, #ffffff00 100%);
}
```

Comment: I am getting invalid property value for webkit .

Comment: that is because `safari` full support for `linear-gradient` since 6.1 so it is deemed as no longer necessary

Comment: Is it ok to have code with error lines for a site?

Comment: sure it might trigger some people but as longs as your website isn't a white screen there will always be some errors that do virtually nothing.

Comment: also firefox has full support since 55 so it also doesn't need the -moz- prefix

Comment: so for most browsers all you really need is `background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0A1326 0%, #0A1326 35%, #ffffff00 35%, #ffffff00 100%);
`

Comment: Thats good to know. Thanks for the help!